# Why I can't align two divs correctly

Tags: html, css

I have one div container called `row3red3`
Inside I have 2 divs, left (`.row3red3slika`) and right(`.row3red3info`).

I can't right divs `.row3red3info` to set on top inline after image.

I tried and set width for .row3red3slika but not working, i have problem i think with row3red3slika width.?

HTML

```
<div class="row3red3">
    <div class"row3red3slika">

        <img src="img/slika2.jpg" alt="Slika2" height="150px" width="215px">

        <div class="imgtext1">
            <span><i class="fa fa-university"></i></span>
        </div><div class="imgtext2">
            <span>PORTSAID EGYPT</span>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row3red3info">

        <span>text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row3red3{
    width:900px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.row3red3slika{
    width:215px;
    height:150px;
}

.row3red3 .imgtext1{
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
background-color:#3E6373;
color:white;
margin-top: 95px;
margin-left:10px;
padding: 4px;
}


.row3red3 .imgtext2{
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
font-size: 14px;
background-color:#3E6373;
color:white;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 60px;
padding: 4px;
}


.row3red3 img{
position: absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;    
}

.row3red3info{


font-size:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `float: left`; to `.row3red3`, `.imgtext1` and `.row3red3info`, and `.row3red3 img`. Also you missed a `=` in:

```
<div class"row3red3slika">
```

it should be:

```
<div class="row3red3slika">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried floating your inner divs?

```
.row3red3info {float:right;}
.row3red3slika{float:left;}
```

Might help to set up a jsfiddle for this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `float:left` . also if you want to get rid of coding  you can use Bootstrap. it does have a perfect grid system that is totally customizable 
here a link to it's grid system tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Comment: no man look i have problem with width of row3red3slika
http://i.imgur.com/2Kb1F89.png